# Vector size is 0 while accessing in Release mode

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a DLL which is exporting a class

```
class EMUDIAG_CLIENT_DLL CEmuDiagnosticsDLL
{
//...
CProjectDataFB  *m_pProjectData;
//...
};

class CProjectDataFB
{
//...
WORD            m_wErrorCode;
vector<EmuComputerData> m_emuComputerData;
//...
};

struct EmuComputerData
{
    DWORD           dwEmuComputerNo;
    WORD            wAPVecSize;
    DWORD           dwIPAddress;        
    vector<DWORD>   apNumbers;          
};
```

DLL does its own operations to fill-in `m_wErrorCode` and `m_emuComputerData`.

I have one EXE which is containing object of `CEmuDiagnosticsDLL` class and try to get `m_wErrorCode` and `m_emuComputerData`.
In debug mode, I get values `m_wErrorCode` and `m_emuComputerData` properly.
**In Release mode, value for `m_wErrorCode` is fine but for `m_emuComputerData` is always 0.**

I am unable to figure out what is causing problem here?

Please don't go into syntax/order of class definitions here as this is mentioned for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sizes (and internal structure) of various STL containers can differ between debug and release builds because of extra safety measures used in debug builds -- for MS Visual C++ specifically, see e.g. [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/309f015b-93a7-4d5b-a739-5cd311bc21c4/vc9x86-sizeofstdvector-2024-bytes?forum=vclanguage).

I suspect the reason you are seeing this weird behavior is because the the DLL and the main applications are built with different configuration (debug/release) or setting of that `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` macro (shown in the linked forum thread). Then you might be lucky to trigger just this "size seems to be 0" problem, it could also simply crash.

The solution is then to keep always both the EXE and DLL parts built with the same configuration (and, of course, the same version of MSVC etc. -- passing C++ objects around across DLL boundaries is not easy), or maybe changing the iterator debugging macro manually to the value you want.

Comment: Thanks a ton...your suggestion solved lot of problems:)